# Which of the fields represents the digital signature value of the CA in a certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

Normally a CA signs the certificate with its private key and produces the digital signature. The digital signature value will be displayed in the certificate.

My question is: what is the field name that shows digital signature value of the CA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field is `Certificate Signature Value`.

For example, this site SSL certificate for : `ssl333133.cloudflaressl.com` has the value :

```
Size: 72 Bytes / 576 Bits
30 46 02 21 00 b7 76 6a 60 32 00 4b 76 49 92 8f 
cb 1a b5 d7 64 55 37 fb 81 0c 65 23 1e 80 b5 a1 
e5 1b 7a 7c 5e 02 21 00 a5 22 6e 4e fe 3a b4 4e 
15 72 e1 d9 48 c8 b5 4a 3e 63 5f c4 d5 34 e7 e6 
6e 87 55 89 8c 28 11 cf
```